# Switching between my accounts

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta

I have 2 accounts: Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow. How can I easily switch between them?

Comment: They are different websites. You can go to either one. What problem are you having?

Comment: You don't. You can be logged into both at the same time. Just visit the site.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Thanks

Comment: Can **you** be more specific?

Comment: You use the same account for all sites. If you want to go to SO from here, just click on the "main" link at the top of the site. And when on SO, click on the "meta" link to get here. If you have two separate accounts but want them merged, see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Comment: I'm in Meta Stackoverflow now. So, how I can go back to Stackoverflow? Do I have to logout and login again each time? Thanks

Comment: You can click the "main" link in the top bar. Boom. Done.

Comment: No need to ever logout when switching from site to site.

Comment: Early April Fools?

Comment: This is a good question as many "new users" will have this same question. They won't realize that they don't have to do anything to switch "accounts" when switching sites. Not everyone will intuit that SO swapped their accounts, particularly when they end up having the same "reputation score" on both sites (ie, just signed up recently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [main](http://stackoverflow.com), click the "meta" link at the top of the page.

From [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), click the "main" link at the top of the page.